# Missing htaccess file on server?

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel, web-development-server

i've just created a website. It's hosted by GoDaddy and I use cPanel to manage it.

all of my files relating to my website are stored in a public_html folder.

The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to access different pages I have uploaded, I'll show what I mean.

- www.website.com --> works fine (defaults to home.html)
- www.website.com/About/about.html --> works fine
- www.website.com.com/About --> I get the error below:

**"You don't have permission to access /About/ on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."**

I would like website.com/About to display about.html.

I think it may be something to do with the .htaccess file? I may of clumsily deleted it at some point.

I have tried to set permissions to 777 on all my public_html files, but I get the same error.

I have tried to locate my htaccess file, but I think its hidden by default. I've tried to find it using a terminal and connecting to my site - also with no success.

Any help to solve this issue would be great cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If `/About/` is a directory and these are static HTML files, rename `about.html` to `index.html`.

Servers will look for index.html in a directory if nothing else was specified in the URL.

Comment: brilliant that worked thanks! However I'm a bit concerned that all my files are going to be called index.html, might get a bit confusing.